# Facebook Graph API: "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action" from IGuser insight endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-opengraph, instagram-api

(#10) Application does not have permission for this action
is now returned by access to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{My IGUser id}/insights?access_token={My token}&period=day&metric=reach
```

My account has more than 100 followers, so I don't think followers are the cause.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{My IGUser id}
```

returned normal data.

The scope is

> email, pages_show_list, business_management, instagram_basic,
> instagram_manage_insights, pages_read_engagement, and public_profile.

This appears to meet the requirements for retrieving IGuser insights information.
Anybody help me please?

Comment: According to the docs, the insights on a 'ig user id' are only allowed on business or creator accounts. Maybe this is your problem: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/insights/

Comment: thank you your helping. 
thats not reason ,my account is business account.

Comment: @devonch Any updates here?